# setting Layer visibility to hidden

Tags: ios, calayer

I am working with a layered image view, and i've created 3 layers for it,

at some point, during runtime, I wish to set one of the layer's hidden state to hidden;

and I would like to know why this code doesn't work for what I want to do

```
-(void)setLayerVisibility:(int)layerNumber visible:(BOOL)visible{
   [[self.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:layerNumber]setHidden:!visible];
    [[self.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:layerNumber]setNeedsLayout];
}
```